# How to externally call a signal in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I know how to call a signal from inside the class where the signal is located: by using `emit`. But what if I want to call it externally, from the parent object?

The reason why I want to do is is because a given QPushButton is connected to a slot which picks the button that called it by using `sender()`. Now I want the same functionallity of that slot to be called but not after a manual click in the button, but from within the code itself. Normally I would just programatically call for the slot, but because of the usage of `sender()`, that way is invalid: calling the slot directly will not give it the id of the button.

So how could I "externally" ask for the object for it to emit one of its signals? That is, how can I make my QPushButton emit its `clicked()` signal from within the code, not by clicking the button with the mouse?

Comment: Why not just call the click() method?

Comment: @MrEricSir because that doesn't work; see my reply to JeremyFriesner down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot emit signal directly from the parent object.

> Only the class that defines a signal and its subclasses can emit the signal. (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals)

You can define a method in your QPushButton `emitClicked()` where you emit the signal. Then you call `emitClicked()` on instance of your QPushButton from the code.

Comment: thanks for the idea with the slot; that's what I have implemented by now, but I wanted a solution to a *direct* call to the signal, which seems to be not available after all. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The Qt headers contain this interesting line (in qobjectdefs.h):

```
#define emit
```

Which means that presence or absence of the emit keyword has no effect on the code, it's only there to make it more obvious to the human reader that you are emitting a signal.  That is to say:

```
 emit clicked();
```

is exactly the same (as far as the C++ compiler is concerned) as

```
 clicked();
```

Given that, if you want your button to emit its clicked() signal, it's just a matter of doing this:

```
 myButton->clicked();
```

(although if you wanted to be clever about it, this would work equally well):

```
 emit myButton->clicked();
```

Comment: to be honest, that was precisely the solution I first thought and tried to implement, without success, before coming to SO. In case, when I call the signal directly by the code, I get the error "error: 'void QImageButton::clicked(button_id)' is protected" - "within this context". So, I would say, your proposed solution don't work. :T

Comment: What's a QImageButton?  AFAICT there's no class named QImageButton in the Qt API.  I tested this technique with a QPushButton and it worked for me there.

Comment: Btw if QImageButton is a subclass of QPushButton, then the problem is probably that the QPushButton::clicked() signal-method is being hidden by QImageButton::clicked(button_id), which is a protected method you aren't allowed to call.  In that case, you can call the QPushButton::clicked() method via something like:  static_cast<QPushButton*>(myButton)->clicked();

Comment: well, that changes things... I used QPushButton as just an example in my question, while my actual solution is implemented over QImageButton, a subclass of QAbstractButton. About clicked(button_id), it is, as I sad, a signal declared under `signals:` in the .hpp of QImageButton and it is emitted when a slot connected to QAbstractButton::clicked() is called. Your "static_cast" solution isn't sufficient for me, since I want the `button_id` information. =]

Comment: If you want the clicked(button_id) signal to be emitted, then call that instead, with the appropriate argument,

Comment: but the problem is that I'm being unable to call `clicked(button_id)` for the reasons mentioned above: error message appears, saying my signal is protected although I never explicitly told it to be so =/ So my problem persists: I'm being unable to *directly* call my signal `clicked(button_id)` while wanting to know if that is possible.

Comment: Is QImageButton class using protected inheritance to derive from its superclass?  If so, you can either change QImageButton to use public inheritance instead, or you can add a public method to QImageButton (or to some subclass of QImageButton) that calls through to clicked(button_id), and call your public method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `Qt Test` module is just for this case.
Check out [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial3-example.html) tutorial on simulating GUI events.
Basically you use [`QTest::​mouseClick`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#mouseClick) and pass pointer to your push button.

Comment: well I'm not sure: `Qt Test`, as the name says, is for tests and that is not what a I want; to use it would be at best "bad code" (we in Brazil would call it a "gambiarra"), and I'm not in favour of such kinds of solution. I would rather prefer to know how Qt Test calls a signal externally and implement that directly. Any suggestions?